# How To Reassemble TCP Packets

Tags: c++

Ok, Ive been searching the net for weeks now.  I have a sniffer in C++ and it's grabbing all of the usual information, what I am missing is the ability to take these TCP packets, reassemble them and parse the HTTP headers.  I'm doing this in Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 C++ with WSA Sockets.  I need some source code so that I can see how this is done.  I've googled and yahoo'd and still don't have the answer.  Why is this so hard to find.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's already a program out there that translates packets into HTML (including the http headers) called firefox. All you need to do is just create a little program that reads and republishes the payload everytime someone connects to its port, and then point your browser at it.

Comment: What sniffer software are you using?  What programming interface does it provide?  What code have you written so far?

Comment: This is my own program written in C++.  It works really great!  I just need to go to the next step and reassemble the TCP packets, I haven't a clue where to go next, as there is next to nothing on this out there!

Answer (score 2):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is an open source sniffer and protocol analyser that can do what you're asking, so I guess its source code has the answer.

Comment: Wow, Thank you!  I have Wireshark but I could never find the source code!  Just did! Thanks to you!  I'm going to run through the code and see what I can find.  In the meantime, I'm still open to suggestions!  The more the merrier as they say!

Comment: But from Wireshark we just can view the packets in Hex format but how to reassemble all packets for a device to get meaningful data? @DSTR3 can u plz give me the link of the source code of Wireshark?

Comment: @MSDPaul: The Wireshark sources are here: https://www.wireshark.org/download.html